# I am encountering an issue with my Dialogflow CX bot where it fails to correctly extract the DNI number from user responses

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have defined a custom entity (@DNIdtmf) to capture DNI numbers.- Included various training phrases covering different ways users might express their DNI numbers.- Checked and tested the custom entity to ensure it recognizes DNI numbers correctly.

Requested Assistance:

I am seeking guidance on how to improve the DNI number extraction in such scenarios.

I tried creating a custom entity and mapped it to the training phrases which I have added to the Capture DNI Page"Oye, necesito revisar eso. Pensaba que era 167, pero ahora tengo la duda de si es 111." which is in Spanish. I approached the Google support team for this issue. They suggested I add a training phrase "@sys.number-sequence:ignore-this-param o no no es @sys.number-sequence:use-this-param".Even then It did not work.

Example:  Agent: Could you please specify your DNI number?
Customer: Let me check its 321 no no its  123
Observed Result :The bot is considering 321 but we want the bot to capture 123 .